# How to use ui-grid E2E testing with jasmine?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, testing, jasmine, angular-ui-grid

I am trying to test my code in [angular-ui-grid](http://ui-grid.info/) using [this tutorial](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/403_end_to_end_testing) in the Jasmine testing framework, but I struggle in doing that. According to the tutorial you shuld require the file `gridTestUtil.scenario.js` and then you can use existing scenarios, but I can't make it work.

I tried doing that, as the tutorial says:

```
var gridTestUtils = require( './gridTestUtils.scenario.js');
gridTestUtils.expectRowCount( 'myGrid', 3 );
```

Is there anyone who could show me how to use their testing scenarios (such as `expectRowCount`, `expectCellValueMatch`, ect.) or to add a code sample.

Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

The file gridTestUtils.scenario.js has been changed to gridTestUtils.spec.js so plz copy the new file in the same folder as as your spec file and try

```
var gridTestUtils = require( './gridTestUtils.spec.js');
gridTestUtils.expectRowCount( 'myGrid', 3 );
```

to get the row count.

Use [This](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/blob/master/test/e2e/gridTestUtils.spec.js) link as reference to cover all the available testing scenarios.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Got it JSK NS. @person101 - The file gridTestUtils.scenario.js has been changed to gridTestUtils.spec.js so plz copy the new file in the same folder as as your spec file and try  var gridTestUtils = require( './gridTestUtils.spec.js');
gridTestUtils.expectRowCount( 'myGrid', 3 ); to get the row count.

Comment: You should probably update the original answer to include this.

Comment: I did what you said but it's still not working for me. My code is: `describe('Testing my grid', function () {
    var gridTestUtils = require('./gridTestUtils.spec.js');
   it('should have 10 visible rows', function () {
       gridTestUtils.expectRowCount('myGrid', 10 );
   });
});` It throws this error to the console: Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined(anonymous function) @ gridTestUtils.spec.js:19, and this error to Jasmine's SpecRunner page: ReferenceError: require is not defined. Is it even possible to use gridTestUtils.spec.js in Jasmine?

Comment: Yes you can definitely use gridTestUtils.spec.js, i used it today for the first time and it worked like a charm

Comment: What scripts do you use? I use angular.js, angular-ui-grid.js and jasmine.js, maybe I am missing something.. Could you upload your code here so I can compare it to mine?